# Maximum subset of set of Integers with minimum distance

Tags: algorithms, integer-programming

Hi, i have a set of integers for example: {0,1,3,100,102} and i am looking for a maximum subset in which all elements have a minimum distance to all elements (or the "next" doesnt matter i guess) for my example ({0,1,3,100,102}) and the distance 3 the result could be: {0,3,100} for distance 2 it could be: {0,3,100,102}

Is there an "good" algorithm to do that ?

(This is my first post, sry when i chose the wrong tag)

Comment: You have chosen the wrong forum for this! Try posting it on stackoverflow.com -- you will get dozens of answers explaining how to solve your problem using dynamic programming.

Comment: isn't this also a mathematical problem ? Something like the Knapsack problem ?

Comment: here i got my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852535/get-largest-subset-of-integers-with-certain-minimum-distance-difference

Comment: To summarize: The obvious greedy algorithm works.